# r in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 'match' requires vector arguments when using calc.niche.overlap in ENMeval package

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the niche overlap between two `.asc` files, output from Maxent.
I have loaded the twp rasters and stacked them.

I have these packages loaded: dismo, enmeval, proc, ecospat and raster.
This is my code, where `env` is my stacked raster:

```
overlap <- calc.niche.overlap(env, overlapStat=I, quiet = FALSE)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Error in match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) : 
  'match' requires vector arguments
```

What does the error mean please and how do I fix it? I am not very good with code!!

Answer (score 0):

My supervisor solved this problem today.
The code should read:

```
overlap <- calc.niche.overlap(env, overlapStat="I", quiet = FALSE)
```